# Face recognition using python/tensorflow in Spring Boot app

Tags: java, python, spring-boot, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am currently working on a server-side web app for the face recognition (using Spring Boot). Face detection should be done using SSD and face recognition using ArcFace. I’ve done some research and found out that such things, related to machine learning, are best to be done in Python. Thus, the next phase of my research was to find out the best way to use Python machine learning along with the Spring boot app. Two suitable (at least in my opinion) approaches are:

1. Use the pre-trained Tensorflow models (using tensorflow dependency for maven). However, the tensorflow model for face recognition would have to be retrained every time face of new person is added to system. What might be the best way to do that in Java? (I was thinking to somehow run a Python script from Java to retrain the model).
2. Build python app with REST API that would be running on a localhost. Java would just send the commands with the images to that REST API and get results (that means – say I’d sent 30 images and also command to carry out the face recognition on these, and then get a list of recognized faces as a result, or send 10 pictures of new person that should be added to system – i.e. app would learn the face).

Could you give me some opinions on which of those 2 approaches is better and why?

ps. Reason why I don't want to build the whole web app in Python is that I already have (some) experience with building Spring boot application while having very little experience with the Python.

Comment: Do you need to update the model immediately after a new face is added? Or you can do the training in Python and load the model in Java once the training is done?

Comment: I think you need to update the model immediately after new face is added, since user may request recognition of faces (that include that new face) shortly after he added that new face.

Comment: I talked about that with collegue and we came to conclusion, that training does not have to be done immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a generic approach, I'd suggest to train the model in a different process (using Python) and once the training is done load it in Java using the [Tensorflow Java API](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/java) for serving (using Spring Boot).

Also you might need some mechanism to replace existing models with new ones if you can't afford to have any downtime (for example the serving layer can be deployed in Kubernetes).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. In my toughts doing extra app for face recognition with REST Api could be better since it would be more independent from rest of system. Can you give me some toughts on why is using tensorflow models from java better?

Comment: @Jakub, I don't fully understand your question, but it was your requirement to use Java for serving.

Comment: My question is, what are advantages of using tensorflow models directly from java (using tensorflow java api) over doing extra tensorflow app for face recognition (that means all the models for face detection, alignment and recognition will be there) and then communicating with this extra app using its REST Api.